Setting prompt using PS1 in a script puts cursor at beginning of line
I want to set the title and prompt in a command line window using the following command:
PS1='\[\e]0;deploy\a\]\[\e[1;32m\]\u@\h\[\e[0m\]:\[\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\$ '

If it is entered interactively, it works fine, but if entered using a script (or a custom bashrc file), the cursor appears at the start of the prompt rather than at the end.
Is there some escaping I am missing?

Can you please post an example of how you want the prompt to look? Copy and pasting it into a shell doesn't change my prompt at all, maybe I'm forgetting something about how this works but the [\e]0;deploy\a] part doesn't seem right looking at it

What is your system? Are you maybe using Windows subsystem for Linux? Are you editing the script/bashrc using a Windows tool?

I am using gnome-terminal on Ubuntu 24.4
The prompt and title (title is set by "[\e]0;deploy\a]") are set correctly, but the cursor is at the beginning of the line (overwriting the prompt) rather than at the end of the line (after the prompt).

Well it doesn't change my (default) prompt a bit, however more to the issue, please answer what @terdon asked, I think he's on the right track

This is all running on pure Ubuntu with tools created using a native linux editor.
I suspect some extra escape characters may be needed when running from within a script.
Other than the positioning of the cusor, everything else works perfectly.

I see no difference between running the command you show manually or adding it to my ~/.bashrc. I suspect you have something else trying to set the prompt or some other issue specific to your setup. Can you try it with a new user? Do you still get the same issue? If not, we've confirmed it is specific to your setup and can try to debug.

So no extra escape sequences required if setting PS1 is done within a script rather than interactively from the command line?
